# ASP.NET Move and modify RadGridView to RadWindow

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik RadGrid consisting of eight columns that I want to display a duplicate of in a pop-up window, after clicking a button. And ideally, it should be a "duplicate" with some of the columns removed. How would I go about this?

I assume I should be able to somehow add the grid to the window's content, manipulate it a little, and then "unmanipulate" and add it back to the main page upon closing the window, using jQuery. I'm just not sure of how to go about this.